# What is the differene between Salesforce Real Time Event Monitoring and Standard Event Monitoring?

Tags: event-monitoring

The context of the logs that are published in both are looking Identical but the logs are different. All I can see is [this](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=real_time_event_monitoring_overview.htm&type=5) documentation. Can someone give a proper difference between the both?

Answer (score 1):

[Real time event monitoring](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=real_time_event_monitoring_overview.htm&type=5) is limited to [selected events](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=real_time_event_monitoring_considerations.htm&type=5):

```
STREAMING               STORAGE             POLICY
ApiEventStream          ApiEvent            ApiEvent
LightningUriEventStream LightningUriEvent   n/a
ListViewEventStream     ListViewEvent       ListViewEvent
LoginAsEventStream      LoginAsEvent        n/a
LoginEventStream        LoginEvent          LoginEvent
LogoutEventStream       LogoutEvent         n/a
ReportEventStream       ReportEvent         ReportEvent
UriEventStream          UriEvent            n/a
```

Real-time event monitoring supports Transaction Security Policies so you can, for example, block the export of report data for sensitive objects.

Real-time event monitoring uses a different data storage mechanism (Big Objects) than the "original" Shield Event Monitoring which uses `EventLogFile` object and were/are intended for consumption by 3rd party logging systems like Splunk or Sumo Logic (although can also be analyzed by the Shield-included Event Monitoring app)

See [Winter 20 Release Notes](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter20/release-notes/rn_security_em_rtem_ga.htm)